# How do I use session and cookies for express.use(express.static('static'))?

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

I have a question about session cookies over web from express backend. In the front I am using a Vue PWA/SPA that is being mounted on express static via `express.use(express.static('static'));` to serve the built files.

I did some research that we can attach options to the function with

```
express.use(cookieParser());
express.use(session({
  secret : `${uuid()}`,
  proxy: true,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 30
  }
}))

const options = {
  dotfiles: 'ignore',
  etag: false,
  extensions: ['html', 'htm'],
  index: false,
  maxAge: '1d',
  redirect: false,
  setHeaders: function(res, path, stat) {
    res.set('Set-Cookie', "myCookie=cookieValue;Path=/");
    res.set('x-timestamp', Date.now());
  }
}
express.use(express.static('static' , options));
```

After doing those, hoping I can read `myCookie=cookieValue` on the browser via `document.cookie` but I don't see those datra being printed on the page.

I have also tried it with `__dirname` method as well and then do

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  req.session.fullname = "Oh mi gee";
  res.render("index");
});
```

didn't give me what I want. Is there a way for me to add session/cookies so I can somewhat secure the API calls by passing cookie data on the header for confirmation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, is to place this `express.static` at the very end of the express configuration.

before we establish `express.static` we will want to do

```
app.use('/path', (req, res, next) => {
  req.session.views++;
  res.cookie('myCookie', 'cookieValue', {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 30
  });
  console.log(req.session);
  next();
})
```

will transfer the cookies to the client side with the expiry of half an hour.